# flask-sqlalchemy. PhoneNumber type

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

`models.py`

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    # phone = db.Column(), nullable=False) what kind of type can be here?
```

---

Я нашел [решение](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.phone_number) при использовании sqlalchemy-utils, однако в flask-sqlalchemy такое решение не поддерживается.

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import PhoneNumber


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    _phone_number = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    phone_country_code = db.Column(db.Unicode(8))

    phone_number = db.orm.composite(
        PhoneNumber,
        _phone_number,
        phone_country_code
    )
```

Получаю следующую ошибку при `flask migrate`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/source/venv/bin/flask", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 966, in main
    cli.main(prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1132, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1171, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 542, in get_command
    rv = info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/source/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/source/project.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app, db
  File "/source/app/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from app import models
  File "/source/app/models.py", line 89, in <module>
    class User(db.Model):
  File "/source/app/models.py", line 101, in User
    phone_number = db.orm.composite(
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'orm'
```

Какие варианты имеются для хранения номера телефона в базе при использовании flask-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Англоязычное сообщество [помогло](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686863/flask-sqlalchemy-phonenumber-type) в решении проблемы.

Необходимо использовать `db.composite` вместо `db.orm.composite`

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import PhoneNumber


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    _phone_number = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    phone_country_code = db.Column(db.Unicode(8))

    phone_number = db.composite(
        PhoneNumber,
        _phone_number,
        phone_country_code
    )
```

---

Так же для себя нашел более подходящую реализацию с помощью PhoneNumberType (см. [подробнее](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.phone_number)).

Прежде необходимо установить дополнительный пакет:
`pip install phonenumbers`

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import PhoneNumberType


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(PhoneNumberType())
```

`user = User(phone_number='+79000000000')`

Так же важно перепроверить сгенерированную версию миграции после вызова `flask migrate`. Лично мне пришлось импортировать `sqlalchemy_utils` вручную:

`import sqlalchemy_utils` вверху файла миграции.